# I'm trying to make an amqp connection. PHP works, but what's wrong with nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

```
<?php
require_once '/usr/share/php/PhpAmqpLib/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('hostname', 5672, 'username', 'password', "vhost", false, 'AMQPLAIN', null, 'en_US', 1160, 1160, null, false, 580);

$channel = $connection->channel();

$queue = 'queue';

$channel->basic_qos(0,1000,false);

$callback = function($msg) {
   #file_put_contents('test.log', "\n===> NEW Message start \n", FILE_APPEND);
   #file_put_contents('test.log', print_r($msg->body, true), FILE_APPEND);
   #file_put_contents('test.log', "\n===> NEW Message end \n", FILE_APPEND);
    echo "=====> Received start\n";
    echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
    echo "=====> Received end\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume($queue, 'consumer', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close()
?>
```

The above php code works fine.
Since it connects to an external server,
it seems that the AMQPStreamConnection option setting of php can be applied to nodejs as it is,
but I am having difficulty modifying the config part of nodejs.
help.

```
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

const config = {
    protocol: 'amqp',
    hostname: 'hostname',
    port: 5672,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    locale: 'en_US',
    vhost: 'vhost',
  }

 amqp.connect(config, function (error0, connection) {
    if (error0) {
        throw error0;
    }
    connection.createChannel(function (error1, channel) {
        if (error1) {
            throw error1;
        }

        var queue = 'queue';

        channel.assertQueue(queue, {
            durable: false
        });

        console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queue);

        channel.consume(queue, function (msg) {
            
            console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
        }, {
            noAck: true
        });
    });
});
```

It works fine in php, but i want to use this in nodejs.

Comment: So...what exact error/problem are you having in the nodeJs code?

Comment: @ADyson  Error: Channel closed by server: 403 (ACCESS-REFUSED) with message "ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'queue' in vhost 'vhost' refused for user 'username'"

Comment: Ok thanks. That's important info, you should [edit] your question to include it, rather than hiding it down in the comments :-)